# Is there a way to specify logging driver for deployed functions

Tags: openfaas

Is there a way to specify logging driver for the functions deployed with OpenFaas.

I have setup fluentd logging driver and would like to configure it for the functions using [openfaas yaml](https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/yaml/) file